# Swift Add Button to UISearchBar / UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I would like to add a button to the left of the search bar. However, I don't want the the scope titles to shift over as well, leaving me with a gap somewhere. I believe my options to be:

- remove scope bar, use UISegmentedControl below, and add a button in
- modify the UISearchBarClass with a button
- ?? container view as header, includes button and search controller ??

Here is my code, refactored to use a UIViewController for easy modification. Note that I am using the `SnapKit` libary for constraints (table cell logic removed). How can I accomplish this?

```
class TeamSearchController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initUI()
    }
    func initUI() {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        initSearchController()
        initTableView()

    }
    func initSearchController() {
        // searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a team here..."

        searchBar.delegate = nil
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Cross Country", "Track"]
        // searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func initTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = nil
        tableView.delegate = nil
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Current Status:
[image]